# Theano is claiming computation graph does not need the most important variable

Tags: python, theano

```
prediction = T.argmax(T.nnet.softmax(w2.dot(T.tanh(w1.dot(x)))));
cost = ((prediction - y)**2).sum();
dw1 = T.grad(cost, w1);
DW1 = dw1.eval({ w1 : W1, x: DATA, y : LABELS });
```

I get the error:

```
UnusedInputError: theano.function was asked to create a function computing
outputs given certain inputs, but the provided input variable at index 1 
is not part of the computational graph needed to compute the outputs: y.
```

This is ridiculous. `y` is DEFINITELY part of the computation graph.

Why is Theano doing this?

Comment: You seem to forget `w2`.

Comment: @sytrus While that is true, Why is the error saying that `y` is not required?

I've since started using `theano.function` directly in place of this `eval` function. It more explicitly defines the necessary inputs for computing an operation and makes me less likely to mistake the necessary inputs, therefore also making me less likely to view ambiguous error messages.

Comment: Error messages of theano can be very confusing. I believe what the error message is trying to say is that there is something wrong with **the inputs** of the output named `y`.